# Prisma DateTime format ( ISO 8601) changes to weird number

Tags: react-native, graphql, prisma

I use Prisma `DateTime` model field as it provides to get `createdAt`.
So it automatically stamped  ISO 8601 format on my db.

`2022-01-20T12:01:30.543Z`

But when I console.log this data on my app, it changes to weird number like `1642680090542`.

What kind of number is this?

And How can I change it to normal date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats the date in `milliseconds`. When you receive this, you can convert it to date again like:

```
var date = new Date(1642680090542);
console.log(date)
```

Comment: But when I console.log createdDate after making `const createdDate = new Date(createdAt);` it says `Date { NaN }` T_T

Comment: it should be var date = new Date(+1642680090542); as adding `+`. then it works! anyway thanks :)

Comment: why does the + fix the problem?

Comment: The + converts it to a number